# .htaccess RewriteRule - multiple replacements needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a photographer, and run a website with thousands of event photos.

Over the years the path to many directories has changed, and, with a new software, the access to individual photos has changed as well.

I get the path changes covered like this (there are many more rules):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})-major-generals-review/?(.*)$ /galleries/trooping-the-colour/$1-major-generals-review/$2 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})-bcn-challenge/?(.*)$ /galleries/canal-and-waterway-events/$1-bcn-challenge/$2 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But I also have to replace, on top of the above, access to individual photos.

The "old" form is, to use a concrete example,

```
2013-bcn-challenge/index.php?`page=11/thumbnails/1305241839185D24543HaraldJoergens_v1.jpg&autoload=1305251137045D25451HaraldJoergens_v1`
```

and what I need is

```
galleries/canal-and-waterway-events/2013-bcn-challenge/1305241839185D24543HaraldJoergens_v1-single.php
```

so there are two replacements needed,

`2013-bcn-challenge` with `/galleries/canal-and-waterway-events/2013-bcn-challenge/` 
(that part does work), and

`index.php?page=11/thumbnails/1305241839185D24543HaraldJoergens_v1.jpg&autoload=1305251137045D25451HaraldJoergens_v1` with

```
1305241839185D24543HaraldJoergens_v1-single.php
```

which does not work. My code for the second replacement is

```
RewriteRule (.*)/index.php?page=[0-9]+/thumbnails/([-_0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.jpg.* $1/$2-single.php  [R=301,NC]
```

on top of the other rules. Unfortunately, it seems to result in an endless loop.

To make matters worse, instead of "/thumbnails/", it could be "/cust_thumbnails/" or "/photos/", and the "autoload" part can be there or not.

Might anyone be able to help me get around the problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Harald

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the query string (`?page=...`) is not part of the request URI, and so cannot be matched in the rewrite pattern.

As such, you will need to check the query string separately:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=\d+/((cust_)?thumbnails|photos)/([\w\-]+).jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?index.php$ /$1%3-single.php? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Here, we are checking the query string for the presence of `page=<num>`, `cust_thumbnails`, `thumbnails`, `photos`, and, of course, the name of the photo.

Then, we are redirecting to `/<folder-name>/<file-name>-single.php`.

**Note:** In the expression, I have changed `[0-9]+` to `\d+` and `[-_0-9a-zA-Z]+` to `[\w\-]+` - these are both shorthand alternatives.